# MongoDB: log mongod to stdout

Tags: mongodb

I have been running MongoDB on my home laptop for awhile now.  running `mongod` outputs to stdout as it should.  super...

I just installed it on my work laptop but it is logging to a file.

```
$ sudo mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

MongoDB should by default be logging to stdout according to the docs.   This installation of mongoDB was done via home brew.  Why is mongod logging to a file, and how do i get it to log to stdout instead?

Comment: Have you tried to comment the logpath setting in /etc/mongodb.conf ?

Comment: it's probably using the settings in /etc/mongodb.conf or similar.

Comment: im not seeing that file.  anywhere else it might be?  maybe home brew puts it somewhere weird.

Answer (score 10):

If you run `` cat `which mongod` `` you can see that the Ruby wrapper around the `mongod` binary appends the default config if the `--config` arguments isn't passed.

```rb
ARGV << '--config' << '/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf' unless ARGV.find { |arg| arg =~ /--config/ }
exec "/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.2.3-x86_64/mongod", *ARGV
```

The default config contains the following

```
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb

# Append logs to /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logpath = /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logappend = true

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

as you can see both `logappend` and `logpath` is set. The `logpath` setting is normally `None` meaning `/dev/stdout`.

To the point. `mongod --config false` will output to STDOUT. That will run the `mongod` binary without a config. If that isn't ideal, change the config settings in `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`.

Answer (score 4):

Besides turning off file logging as others have suggested, you can also do the following:

```
sudo mongod; tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

Answer (score 4):

from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.destination):

> **systemLog.destination** Type: string
>
> The destination to which MongoDB sends all log output. Specify either
>   file or syslog. If you specify file, you must also specify
>   systemLog.path.
>
> If you do not specify systemLog.destination, MongoDB sends all log
>   output to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, it is likely that you have the "logpath" setting made in a configuration file. If you don't know where that is, you can find that out by running mongod like:

```
sudo su -
strace -e open mongod
```

This spits out some information - every file mongod tries to open - in which you should be able to find the config file. For me, it looked like this (partially):

```
…
open("/proc/cpuinfo", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 3
open("/etc/mongodb.conf", O_RDONLY)     = 4
all output going to: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
open("/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 4
open("/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 1
…
```

After you have found the file, comment out (with a #) the logpath= line and your log should be output to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine brew created a mongod.conf file in `/usr/local/etc/`.

Moreover, you should see something like this in line 7 (or so) of your log file `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`:

```
Tue Jan  8 10:14:25 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question and above answer might not be valid anymore.

Documentation says:

> `systemLog.destination` Type: string
>
> The destination to which MongoDB sends all log output. Specify either
> file or syslog. If you specify file, you must also specify
> systemLog.path.
>
> If you do not specify systemLog.destination, MongoDB sends all log
> output to standard output.

Changing the configuration file `/etc/mongod.conf` does not work for me.

```
$ cat /etc/mongod.conf
# mongod.conf for MongoDB local Server

# where to write logging data.
#systemLog:
#  destination: file
#  logAppend: true
#  logRotate: reopen
#  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mediation/mongodb
  directoryPerDB: true 


$ mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
BadValue: --fork has to be used with --logpath or --syslog
```

Also this one is failing:

```
$ mongod  --config /etc/mongod.conf --logpath ""
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-24T12:43:20.863Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":2,"codeName":"BadValue","errmsg":"logpath cannot be empty if supplied"}}}
```

The solution for me is this one:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --logpath /proc/$$/fd/0
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemlog-options):

> If you do not specify `systemLog.destination`, MongoDB sends all log output to standard output.

Tested the below configuration in `mongod.conf` and it works, even on older releases (I tested as far as version [4.2.22](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/4.2/#4.2.22---aug-19--2022) released on Aug 19, 2022):

```
systemLog:
  logAppend: true
  # do not set below 
  #destination:
  #path:
```